# A problem involves Mittag-Leffler theorem and Weierstass Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

$G$ is a region,$\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_m\}$ are two sequence of distinct points in $G$ without limit in G.And $a_n\neq b_m$ for all $n,m$.Let $S_n(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{m_n}\frac{A_{jn}}{(z-a_n)^j} $.We are required to find a $f\in M(G)$ such that $f$ only has poles and zeros at $a_n$ and $b_m$ with singular part at $a_n$ is $S_n(z)$ and order of zero at $b_m$ is $p_m$.

  My rough idea is find a form like $g\cdot h $,where $g$ is first found by Weierstrass theorem,$g\in H(G)$,only has zeros at $b_m$ with order $p_m$;$h$ is found by Mittag-Leffler theorem,$h\in M(G)$,only has poles at $a_n$ with singular part $r_n(z)$,which is chosen to make $g\cdot h$ has singular part at $a_n$ is $S_n(z)$.
Now $g\cdot h$ will have poles only at $a_n$ with described singular part,has zeros at $b_m$.Zeros and poles won't cancel with each other.But what if there are some other zeros in $h$?Mittag-Leffler theorem doesn't assert that a non-vanishing meromorphic function with prescribed poles and singular part could be found.I don't know how to rule out the zeros in $h$.